# C# Testing method with StorageFile as parameter

Tags: c#, mocking, windows-runtime, nunit, .net-4.5

First of all, this is a **Microsoft Store** winrt library and I am trying to test a public method with this signature:

```
string GetStringFromFile(StorageFile storageFile);
```

But `StorageFile` doesn't have a constructor, so I cannot create it on my NUnit test code.  Also, I think I can not use `Moq` or any other Mocking library on WinRt.

I have been looking for create a hand-made fake from IStorageFile Interface but it has a lot of methods inside and I have, again, stucked on another deep-properties pointing out to clases without public constructor inside `StorageFile` as `ImageProperties` in example.

So... What is the best way to test a method with `StorageFile` and/or `ImageProperties` classes ?

Comment: You could create a StorageFileWrapper class that takes an IStorageFile as argument to its ctor. With this wrapper you can create any methods you like which forwards calls to the wrapped object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StorageFile` class implements an interface [IStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.istoragefile.aspx) so you should change your dependency to that, you can then use a mock or stub (possibly a class you create if you can't use Moq etc).

Comment: Programming to interfaces rather than concrete classes is the way to go for mocking.

Comment: You should always depend on abstractions rather than implementations, not just because it makes mocking easier (it's the D in SOLID principles)

Comment: Ok, perhaps I have not expressed my question in the right way.  `StorageFile` has `IStorageFile` interface, I know.  But `ImageProperties` (also in my example) doesn't have any interface implementing property `CameraManufacturer` in example.  How to test this second one class ?

Comment: @Ferpega Ah OK, I see what you mean now. It seems the interface doesn't contain all the properties that the class specifies. Based upon that, you have 2 options. 1) create a wrapper class which exposes it's own interface which you can program against 2) make the parameter type dynamic then you can send it anything which has the correct property names.

Comment: @Trevor Pilley I understand both of two ways but I think I prefer the wrapper one. :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this method is one of yours, not something in another library you cannot control; I would change the signature so the parameter is of IStorageFile type instead of the concrete class. Then, you can create a fake of it for your test, but use a real StorageFile in the application.